# panel popup is taking more time to close on click of close button in panel

Tags: c#, html, .net, webforms

I have a `GridView` control, and inside of this control I have defined a link button using `GridView.ItemTemplate`.

I am using this to open a new window on click. When I click on the link button, however, the page refreshes before opening the new window.

How can I stop the page from refreshing after the link button is clicked?

Pop up is not displaying when i add Update panel to first grid

if i remove Update panel from first grid, grid is refreshing and popup is displaying

I need to open a popup without refreshing my grid

PLEASE FIND ME THE SOLUTION FOR THIS AS I WAS WORKING ON THIS FROM PAST 2 DAYS

**HTML**

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="ViewData1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ablesas.ViewDataUI1" EnableEventValidation="false"%>


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel4" runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>

                                         <asp:GridView ID="DataGrid1"  style="visibility:visible" runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#E9EDF5"  Font-Names="Arial"
                                                ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="12px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray" Font-Bold="true" 
                                                HeaderStyle-BackColor="#298DC7" EnableViewState="false"  CellSpacing="20" 
                                                CellPadding="10"  HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="DataGrid1__RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="DataGrid1__RowDataBound" >
                                                <HeaderStyle Font-Names="Arial;" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" Height="20"  BackColor="#298DC7" ></HeaderStyle>
        <asp:templatefield headertext="NDC" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Justify" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Width="10%">                                     <Columns>               
                    <itemtemplate>
                    <asp:linkbutton id="productcode"   ForeColor="#09538A" runat="server"  text='<%#Eval("product code")%>'></asp:linkbutton>                               

                                                     </itemtemplate>
                                        </asp:templatefield>
                   </asp:GridView>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>


                                        <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="cancel" TargetControlID="Button3" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"> </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel id="Panel1"  runat="server" Height="30px" Width="600px">
    </asp:Panel>        
                   <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" style="visibility:hidden" Text="Button" />
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlpopup" CssClass="PanelPopup"  runat="server">
                                        <div  style="width:inherit;text-align:center;">Products of <%=ndc %> Product Family</div>
                                        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"  runat="server" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#f1f4f8"  Width="980px" Font-Names="Arial"
                                            Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#09538A" Font-Size="13px" BackColor="#ffffff" BorderColor="DarkGray"
                                            HeaderStyle-BackColor="#99cccc" EnableViewState="false"  CellSpacing="0" style="padding:10px;"
                                            CellPadding="3" ShowFooter="false" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="productInfo_RowDataBound" >
                                            <HeaderStyle Height="10%" CssClass="MyHeaderStyle" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="true"  BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
                                            <rowstyle Height="20px" />
                        <alternatingrowstyle  Height="20px"/>
                                            <Columns>
                <asp:boundfield  datafield="product code" sortexpression="customers " ItemStyle-CssClass="col" headertext="NDC"/>

             <div id="div<%#  Convert.ToString(Eval("customer"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("ManufacturingPartner"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("product code"))+ Convert.ToString(Eval("Sales Person")) %>" style="display: none; position: relative; left: 15px; overflow: auto">
                                        <asp:GridView ID="gvOrderInfo" runat="server" ForeColor="#09538A"  AutoGenerateColumns="false" BorderStyle="Double"  BorderColor="#df5015"  Width="500px" OnRowDataBound="gvOrderInfo_RowDatabound">
                                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="MyHeaderStyle"  Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" Font-Bold="True"  BackColor="#298DC7"></HeaderStyle>
                                        <RowStyle BackColor="#E1E1E1" />
                                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="White" />
                                        <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Order Number" HeaderText="Order Number" ItemStyle-Width="75px" ItemStyle-CssClass="col" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                  </Columns>   
              </Columns>                            
                                        </asp:GridView>
                                    </div>                         
                                            </asp:GridView>
             </asp:Panel>
```

**Codebehind**

```
  protected void DataGrid1__RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {    
         this.UpdatePanel4.Update();
         if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
         {
              LinkButton lnk = e.Row.FindControl("productcode") as LinkButton;
              lnk.Click += new EventHandler(link_Click);

              //ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(lnk); 

              // string a = String.Format("0:N}",Convert.ToDecimal(e.Row.Cells[3].Text));
              if (e.Row.Cells[0].Text != "Total")
              {
                    //M1-Fmodification starts from here
                    if (ListBox2.Items.Count > 0)
                    //if (DataGrid1.Columns[0].Visible == true)
                    {
                    }              
              }
         }
    }
```

**Codebehind**

```
 public void productcode_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlpopup.Visible = true;
            //UpdatePanel3.Update();
            //this.UpdatePanel3.Update();
            GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
            LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)clickedRow.FindControl("productcode");
            string customer = clickedRow.Cells[0].Text.ToString();
            string manufacturer = clickedRow.Cells[5].Text.ToString();
            string salesperson = clickedRow.Cells[6].Text.ToString();
            System.Data.DataTable newProductTable = null;
            ArrayList productDrilldownList = new ArrayList();
            productDrilldownList.Add(customer);
            productDrilldownList.Add(manufacturer);
            productDrilldownList.Add(lbtn.Text);
            productDrilldownList.Add(salesperson);


            try
            {
                ViewData1 vData = new ViewData1();
                DataSet ds1 = vData.__getProdOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds2 = vData.__getCustOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds3 = vData.__getSalesOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds4 = vData.__getManOverviewDataSet(__getConnectionString());
                DataSet ds5 = vData.__getBookedDateDataSet(__getConnectionString());

                List<DateTime> booked_date = new List<DateTime>();

                if (ds5.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in ds5.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (row[0].ToString() != " " && row[0] != null)
                        {
                            booked_date.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]));
                        }
                    }
                }
                booked_date.Remove(Convert.ToDateTime("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"));
                booked_date.Sort();
                ArrayList daterange = new ArrayList();
                daterange = _getDateRange();
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[0]) > Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[1]))
                {
                 //   DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                 //   Label4.Visible = false;
                //    TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                //    Panel1.Visible = false;
                //    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");
                //    return;
                }
                if (ToDateTxtBox.Text != "" && ToDateTxtBox.Text != "To Date" && FromDateTxtBox.Text != "From Date")
                {
                    DropDownList2.Text = "Months";
                    DropDownList3.Text = "Years";
                    if (!booked_date.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[2])) && !booked_date.Contains(Convert.ToDateTime(daterange[3])))
                    {
                     //   DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                     //   Label4.Visible = false;
                    //    TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                    //    Panel1.Visible = false;
                    //    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ToDateTxtBox.Text = "";
                    FromDateTxtBox.Text = "";
                }




                int countCustomer = -1;
                int countProduct = -1;
                int countSales = -1;
                int countMan = -1;
                if (ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countProduct = ds1.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countCustomer = ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countSales = ds3.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }
                if (ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    countMan = ds4.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                }


                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
                string test = "";
                if(Session["callcount"] != null){
                    string coo = Session["callcount"].ToString(); 
                    int coi = Int16.Parse(coo);
                    Session["callcount"] = coi + 1;
                    test = Session["callcount"].ToString();
                }
                else{
                    int coi = 0;
                    Session["callcount"] = coi.ToString();
                    test = Session["callcount"].ToString();
                }
                dt = vData.__getProductLevelSource(__getConnectionString(), __getDropDownValues(), __getProdFilterValues(), __getCustFilterValues(), __getSalesFilterValues(), __getManFilterValues(), countCustomer, countProduct, countSales, countMan, _getDateRange(), __getProdFamilyFilterValues(), productDrilldownList);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                //dt.Rows.Count
                Gridview_Columnshide(GridView1);
            }
            catch (Exception dateerr)
            {
                //DataGrid1.Visible = false;
                //Label4.Visible = false;
                //TxtCustProd.Visible = false;
                //Panel1.Visible = false;
                //ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "Javascript", "<script>alert('There is no data found')</script>");

            }

            ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
            //UpdatePanel3.Update();

        }
```

Comment: can you post correct codes from your project, in both aspx and c# file? Those codes you posted doesn't make any sense, `productcode` LinkButton doesn't have any onclick event... lot of controls don't have closing tag... Again the idea is that: put everything in your page inside an updatepanel, but we'll see after you update your code

Comment: the problem is i gave to bind the grid in postback also so in my page load i have a code like this if(!IsPostBack){   } Gridbind(); so it is refreshing for this ineed the solution. As per my requirement i need to  bing the grid in postback also

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `DataGrid1.Datsource` and `DataGrid1.Databind();` in your `onPage_Load()`
Since this will get called when you press a button.

`DataGrid1.DataSource = ...;`  in combination with `DataGrid1.DataBind();` updates all values in your gridview to the values from the defined list.

This means that when you have this in your `onPage_Load()` it will refresh the gridview.

Comment: i was binding the grid in after postback also as  if(!ispostback{   } bindgrid(); as per my requirement

Comment: So you wanna sometimes update it on page reload and sometimes not?

Comment: yes Exactly you are right

Comment: Entire page is reloading on click of link button and popup is displaying if i don't use update panel,  If i use update panel page is not refreshing but popup is not displaying

Comment: I don't know how to do this so I can't help you any further.

Comment: Thank you for your time and consideration i have found solution myself by just adding Enabled="false" to modalpopuoextender

Comment: now i was facing another issue

Comment: i have a  Close button in panel on click of that it is closing the panel very late(it is taking time to close the panel). but  i need to close the panel just if user clicks on it.  Sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Here the strcuture:

First of all, put this on top of your page, right under `ContentPlaceHolder1` if you are using masterpage or right under the form tag if you are not

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Next, we create an UpdatePanel and EVERYTHING in the page will be put INSIDE this UpdatePanel (you can have other UpdatePanel but this is the outer one) this will ensure the page will not be refresh/reload on any click event (`<trigger>` is not needed for this outer UpdatePanel). Use `HiddenField` for TargetCOntrolID of ModalPopupExternder instaed of button.

```
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DisplayAfter="10" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
         <ProgressTemplate>
            <div style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; border: none; z-index: 100; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: #999; filter: alpha(opacity=80); -moz-opacity: .8; opacity: .8;">
                <img src="http://www.ajaxload.info/images/exemples/29.gif" style="top: 50%; left: 50%; position: relative;" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>

            //all your contents will be here

            //Your DataGrid1 with LinkButton inside...
            <AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1"   BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" CancelControlID="cancel" TargetControlID="HiddenField1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlpopup"> </AjaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
            // Your pnlpopup Panel

        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Don't use UpdatePanel.Update() function, if you want to update your gridview, update your dataset and call Gridview.Databind() method.

If you want to use other UpdatePanel inside ModalPopupExtender, just put everything inside the Panel, but this time you will need `<Triggers>` for buttons inside this UpdatePanel (rather than the cancel/close popup button)

Comment: it stopped reload the grid but popup is not showing on clcik of link button

Comment: just copy and past ALL codes here, we'll see what's going down there.